# AOP Advices not running in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to use simple logging aspect in my application, but the advices are not running and am not getting any logs in the console.

**Dependencies added**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Entity class**

```java
package com.ayushsingh.aopproject.entity;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Integer age;
    private Long phone;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }
    public Integer getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(Integer age) { this.age = age; }
    public Long getPhone() { return phone; }
    public void setPhone(Long phone) { this.phone = phone; }
}
```

**Aspect class**

```java
package com.ayushsingh.aopproject.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

     LoggingAspect() {
          System.out.println("Logging Aspect instansiated");
     }

     // -Run before a getter
     @Before("execution(public String com.ayushsingh.aopproject.entity.Student.getName())")
     public void LoggingAdvice1() {
          System.out.println("Advice 1");
     }

     // - Run before a method of a particular class
     @Before("execution(public String com.ayushsingh.aopproject.entity.Student.getName())")
     public void LoggingAdvice2() {
          System.out.println("Adivce 2");
     }

     // - Run before all getters
     @Before("execution(public String com.ayushsingh.aopproject.*.get*())")
     public void LoggingAdvice3() {
          System.out.println("Advice 3");
     }

     // - Run before all setters (methods with argument)
     @Before("execution(public void com.ayushsingh.aopproject.*.set*(*))") // -one or more arguments
     public void LoggingAdvice4() {
          System.out.println("Advice 4");
     }

     // -for getters of all entity classes in the entity package
     @Before("execution(public * com.ayushsingh.aopproject.entity.*.get*())")
     public void LoggingAdvice5() {
          System.out.println("Advice 5");
     }

}
```

**Main class**

```java
package com.ayushsingh.aopproject;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import com.ayushsingh.aopproject.entity.Student;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopProjectApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // -Create Student object
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(1L);
        student.setAddress("Address 1");
        student.setAge(25);
        student.setName("Ayush");
        student.setPhone(8145000047L);
        String name=student.getName();
        System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());
    }

}
```

Now on running the application I must get the logs from the advices also, but as I also checked using debugger and breakpoints, the aspects are not running at all.

The output I get is

```
2024-02-07T15:20:41.325+05:30  INFO 21704 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.aopproject.AopProjectApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-07T15:20:41.408+05:30  INFO 21704 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
Logging Aspect instansiated
2024-02-07T15:20:42.527+05:30  INFO 21704 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-02-07T15:20:42.607+05:30  INFO 21704 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.aopproject.AopProjectApplication     : Started AopProjectApplication in 1.732 seconds (process running for 2.185)
Name: Ayush
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call component constructors directly, let the Spring container do that for you by calling `getBean(..)` on the application context returned by `SpringApplication.run()`, currently discarded by you.

Please also be advised to read at least minimal documentation when using a new technology, or maybe start from a functioning sample application and work your way up to more features, always just changing small bits which you can revert, if something is not working.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I somehow added @Component and forgot about it. I am completely aware about its use and beans in Spring. I have rectified it, but the problem is still the same. Can you help with that?

Comment: Certainly. Just post a link to your full Maven project on GitHub. I can take a look as soon as I finish work and am near my personal computer again.

Comment: But why did you do the opposite of what I told you to do? I just noticed your edit. Instead of using Spring to instantiate the component, you even removed the `@Component` annotation and are still using `new`. That just makes matters worse. Did you even read what I wrote in my answer?